# OpenTok publisher volume adjustment

Tags: opentok

I am using OpenTok Client SDK. I need to scale the current speaker video block. I tried to use [audioLevelUpdated](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#events) event to check the current speaker. Is OpenTok have that functionality?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the some identification to each subscriber. And then Add the button to each subscriber name to increase/decrease the audio.

With this method

```
subscriber1.setAudioVolume(50);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mean that when speaks Speaker 1 scale own video block when speaks Speaker 2 scale its video block.

Comment: u need develop some custom flow. Ex speaker 1 click and u record that click as  he is now speaker, on that basis u resize all the video blocks. If u try to catch the speaker based on active audio then all the participants will experience the moving blocks all the time.  Because all even small cough sound will mark as active audio.